# Difference between BigMemory Go or EhCache and BigMemory Max in terms of distributed environment and replication

Tags: ehcache, distributed-cache, ehcache-bigmemory

Can anybody help me understand the difference in ehcache or BigMemory GO and BigMemory Max in terms of support for distributed caches and replication? I see that using RMIEventListener, ehCache also supports distributed caching while BigMemory Max uses Terracota server array. How does it impacts performance? What are the differences between these two techniques?